# Helen as well as her friends __ a lot about the new cocktail. The verb form

Tags: grammar

I am just want to be sure, the blank space should be filled with the original form of a verb or plural form of a verb in accordance to grammar rules?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> Helen as well as her friends __ a lot about the new cocktail.

The subject is Helen; hence, we need the third-person singular verb.

*as well as her friends* is parenthetical and does not affect the choice of the verb.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20well%20as) explains.

> in addition to : BESIDES
>
> the coach, as well as the team, is ready